# reopen minimized window visual studio application developpment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

im using visual studio to make a screen recorder using the ScreenRecorderLib library (but it is not related to my question) and c#. It is my first app ever even though i made some games in unity using c#.
I want to, on record button click or keyboard shortcut (for example crtl+a), to minimize the window in taskbar. I managed to do this using

```
private void RecordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveControl = null;

        try
        {
            if (_IsRecording)
            {
                //some actions to stop recording (not interresting for my question)
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            UpdateProgress();

            

            if (_rec == null)
            {
                // some actions to make settings active and launch the recording
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            }


        }}
```

and my code for the shortcuts

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "A")
            {
                RecordButton.PerformClick();
            }
        }
```

This is not my real code but i tried to select some interresting parts for my question.
I manage to minimize my button in taskbar with shortcut or with button, but not to stop the recording using the shortcut while it is minimized. I would like that while recording and window minimised to be able to click crtl+a to stop the recording

Any ideas???

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

"How to use shortcut keys when the application is inactive" has been collected in API: MouseKeyHook.

You only need to modify the operations you need in the appropriate places.

[globalmousekeyhook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook/blob/vNext/keycomb.md)

Sample:

```
nuget install MouseKeyHook
```

```
public bool Flag { get; set; }

private void MinOrNarmal() {
    //1. Define key combinations
    var undo = Combination.TriggeredBy(Keys.A).With(Keys.Control);
    //2. Define actions
    Action actionUndo = DoSomething;
    void DoSomething() {
        if (Flag == false) {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            Flag = true;
            return;
        }
        if (Flag == true) {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            Flag = false;
        }
    }
    //3. Assign actions to key combinations
    var assignment = new Dictionary<Combination, Action> { { undo, actionUndo } };
    //4. Install listener
    Hook.GlobalEvents().OnCombination(assignment);
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MinOrNarmal();
}
```

Press "Control+A":

[image]

[You can also write global hotkeys yourself.](https://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/globale-hotkeys-tastenkombinationen/356)

Only realize the function of shrinking the window：

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.KeyPreview = true;
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A) {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it help you?

Comment: i actually after 5  hours of research, found another solution. Indeed yours yorked but had many bugs, stopped working after opening some windows... Without any nuGet package i fond an exellent way that i will put in the comments to help other peoples who might have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

https://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/how-to-register-a-global-hotkey-for-your-application-in-c/#comments

This perfectly answers my question. I will put a code down below for the people who want to have more than one shortcut. I'm a beginner, so mabe my explanations are not correct, but i tried to explain them in the esasiest way and in the way i understood them

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id1, int fsModifiers, int vk);
        //for creating another hotKey
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey1(IntPtr hWnd, int id2, int fsModifiers, int vk);
//here you can create even more shortcuts

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id1);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey1(IntPtr hWnd, int id2);
//remember unreg them
        enum KeyModifier
        {
            None = 0,
            Alt = 1,
            Control = 2,
            Shift = 4,
            WinKey = 8
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int id1 = 0;     // The id of the hotkey. 
            RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, id1, (int)KeyModifier.Shift, Keys.F1.GetHashCode());
            int id2 = 1;     // The 2nd id of the hotkey. 
            RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, id2, (int)KeyModifier.Shift, Keys.F2.GetHashCode());// Register Shift + A as global hotkey. 
        }


        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);

            if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
            {

                if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 0)
                {
                    RecordButton.PerformClick();
                }
                if(m.WParam.ToInt32() == 1)
                {
                    PauseButton.PerformClick();
                }
                //add the other shortcuts just replace == 1 by the id value
            }
        }

        private void ExampleForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, 0);       // Unregister hotkey with id 0 before closing the form. You might want to call this more than once with different id values if you are planning to register more than one hotkey.
            UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1);
        }
//delete them with the id
```